Totalization of the morphism between the two possible canonical truncations induces a quasi-isomorphism (Lemma 12.5.2 of Kashiwara, Schapira)
$\def\A{\mathcal{A}}$Given an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, we denote $\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{A})$ to the category of cochain complexes with terms in $\mathcal{A}$. I am trying to understand the proof of the following result from Kashiwara, Schapira, Categories and Sheaves:

Lemma 12.5.2. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category. Let $\left(X^{\bullet ,\bullet}, d^{\prime}, d^{\prime \prime}\right) $ be a double complex such that for each $n$ there is a finite amount of non-zero $X^{i,j}$ for $i+j=n$. Then the natural morphism $\operatorname{tot}\left(\tau_I^{\leq q}(X)\right) \rightarrow \operatorname{tot}\left(\widetilde{\tau}_I^{\leq q}(X)\right)$ is a qis for all $q$.

Here's the meaning of the notation:

Given a double complex $K^{\bullet,\bullet}$, the complex $\operatorname{tot}(K^{\bullet,\bullet})$ is defined as $\operatorname{tot}(K^{\bullet,\bullet})^n=\bigoplus_{i+j=n}K^{i,j}$ and with differentials as usual.

Given an abelian category $\A$, there are truncation functors $\tilde{\tau}^{\leq n},  \tau^{\leq n}: \mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \mathrm{C}^{-}(\mathcal{C})$
defined as follows. Let $X:=\cdots \rightarrow X^{n-1} \rightarrow X^n \rightarrow X^{n+1} \rightarrow \cdots$. We set:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \tau^{\leq n} X:=\cdots \rightarrow X^{n-2} \rightarrow X^{n-1} \rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}d_X^n  \rightarrow 0 \;\;\,\quad \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots \\
& \tilde{\tau}^{\leq n} X:=\cdots \rightarrow X^{n-2} \rightarrow X^{n-1}  \rightarrow X^n \quad\;\, \rightarrow \operatorname{Im} d_X^n \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
There is a natural morphism of complexes $\tau^{\leq n}X\to\tilde{\tau}^{\leq n} X$.

We define $\tau_I^{\leq n}=F_I^{-1}\circ\tau^{\leq n}\circ F_I$ (and analogously for $\tilde{\tau}^{\leq n}$), where $F_I:\mathrm{C}^2(\mathcal{C})\to\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C}))$ denotes the isomorphism from the category $\mathrm{C}^2(\mathcal{C})$ of double complexes with terms in $\mathcal{C}$ that sends a double complex $(X,d',d'')\in\mathrm{C}^2(\mathcal{C})$ to $X_I\in\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C}))$, defined by $X_I^n=\{X^{n,\bullet},d''^{n,\bullet}_X\}$ and $d_{X_I}^n=d'^{n,\bullet}_X$.


In the book we find:

Proof of Lemma 12.5.2. We have an exact sequence in $\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C}))$
$$
\tag{1}\label{tr}
0 \rightarrow \tau_I^{\leq q}(X) \rightarrow \widetilde{\tau}_I^{\leq q}(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{Mc}\left(\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Im} d_X^{\prime q}[-q-1]}\right) \rightarrow 0 .
$$
Since $\operatorname{tot}$ is an exact functor, we get the exact sequence
$$
\label{ses}\tag{2}
0 \rightarrow \operatorname{tot}\left(\tau_I^{\leq q}(X)\right) \rightarrow \operatorname{tot}\left(\widetilde{\tau}_I^{\leq q}(X)\right) \rightarrow \operatorname{tot}\left(\operatorname{Mc}\left(\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Im} d_X^{\prime q}[-q-1]}\right)\right) \rightarrow 0 .
$$
Since
$$
\label{iso}\tag{3}
\operatorname{tot}\left(\operatorname{Mc}\left(\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Im} d_X^{\prime q}[-q-1]}\right)\right) \simeq \operatorname{Mc}\left(\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Im} d_X^{\prime q}[-q-1]}\right)
$$
and this complex is exact, we get the result from the l.e.s. in cohomology that \eqref{ses} induces. $\square$

(Here $\operatorname{Mc}$ denotes mapping cone. The s.e.s. \eqref{tr} is (12.3.2) in the book.)
My only question is: How can we have the isomorphism \eqref{iso}? The functor $\operatorname{tot}:\mathrm{C}(\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C}))\to\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C})$ has different domain and codomain, and it seems we are giving an isomorphism between an object in the domain and its image under $\operatorname{tot}$, which are quite different things.

$\def\A{\mathcal{A}}
\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\Mc{\operatorname{Mc}}
\def\id{\operatorname{id}}$It seems the book is overloading notation. I'm going to write the isomorphism in a precise way by refining the notation. Given an abelian category $\A$ and a morphism $f$ of chain complexes with terms in $\A$, I'll denote $\Mc_{\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{A})}f\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathrm{C}(\A))$ to the mapping cone of $f$, and we write $\iota^\A_n=\iota_n:\A\to\mathrm{C}(\A)$ to the canonical injection $\iota_n(A)^m=A$ if $m=n$ and $\iota_n(A)^m=0$ otherwise. Typically this is written in the literature simply as $A[n]$, but this is where the confusion arises from. We reserve the notation $[n]:\mathrm{C}(\C)\to\mathrm{C}(\C)$ to signify exclusively the canonical shift (where $\C$ is abelian).
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism in $C(\mathcal{C})$. Write $\A=\mathrm{C}(\mathcal{C})$. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have a general isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{tot}\left(
\underset{\mathrm{C}(\A)}{\Mc}(\iota_nf)
\right)
\cong\underset{\mathrm{C}(\C)}{\Mc}(f[n]).
$$
To prove such an isomorphism exists, one uses Examples 11.3.5.(i) and 11.5.7. Setting $f=\id_{\operatorname{Im} d_X^{\prime q}}$ and $n=-q-1$ gives what is intended in \eqref{iso}.
